# ExpandableListView sqlite error

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a database with event names and dates.  I am trying to create an expandablelistview using cursors that will have the events grouped by event date.

I'm not finding a lot of information relevant to my situation regarding it.  The example in the SDK is using a content provider and I haven't read-up/experimented with that yet and I already have the database helper set up the old way.

I found what I thought was a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261126/android-expandablelistactivity-and-simplecursortreeadapter) and tried to adapt it to my use, however it is crashing and I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

**my code**

```
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter;

public class ExpandableListTestActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    private AttendanceDB mDbHelper;  
    private Cursor mGroupsCursor; 
    private int mGroupIdColumnIndex; 
    private MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

                    mDbHelper = new AttendanceDB(this); 
                    mDbHelper.open(); 
                    fillData(); 
    } 

    private void fillData() { 
                    mGroupsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchGroup();   
                    startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor); 

                    mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor,this, 
                                                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, 
                                                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, 
                                                    new String[] { AttendanceDB.EVENT_DATE }, 
                                                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 
                                                    new String[] { AttendanceDB.EVENT_NAME }, 
                                                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }); 
                    setListAdapter(mAdapter); 
    } 

    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter { 

                    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context, 
                                                    int groupLayout, int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, 
                                                    int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) { 
                                    super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, 
                                                                    childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo); 
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) { 
                                    Cursor childCursor = mDbHelper 
                                                                    .fetchChildren(groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(AttendanceDB.EVENT_DATE))); 
                                    startManagingCursor(childCursor); 
                                    return childCursor; 
                    } 
    } 
}
```

When I run this code I get the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30329): FATAL    EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(30329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cdc.workshopapps.explist/cdc.workshopapps.explist.ExpandableListTestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:436)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.getId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:437)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:192)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getItemId(ExpandableListConnector.java:421)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(AdapterView.java:744)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.widget.AdapterView.setSelectedPositionInt(AdapterView.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:458)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.ExpandableListActivity.setListAdapter(ExpandableListActivity.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at cdc.workshopapps.explist.ExpandableListTestActivity.fillData(ExpandableListTestActivity.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at cdc.workshopapps.explist.ExpandableListTestActivity.onCreate(ExpandableListTestActivity.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
E/AndroidRuntime(30329):    ... 11 more
```

Which I take to mean there's something wrong with the columns I'm returning in my cursor.  But if I change the filldata() method to the following (just to check my cursors/columns):

```
mGroupsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchGroup();
startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor);
mGroupsCursor.moveToFirst();
String Text1 = mGroupsCursor.getString(mGroupsCursor.getColumnIndex(AttendanceDB.EVENT_DATE));
Toast.makeText(this, Text1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Cursor childCursor = mDbHelper
        .fetchChildren(mGroupsCursor.getString(mGroupsCursor.getColumnIndex(AttendanceDB.EVENT_DATE)));
startManagingCursor(childCursor);
childCursor.moveToFirst();
String Text2 = childCursor.getString(childCursor.getColumnIndex(AttendanceDB.EVENT_NAME));
Toast.makeText(this, Text2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The toasts output the expected event date and event name data, so I'm at a loss as to where I've gone wrong.

Other (perhaps) relevant code:

```
public Cursor fetchGroup() {
    String query ="SELECT DISTINCT date FROM events"; 
      return mDb.rawQuery(query,null); 
}

public Cursor fetchChildren(String date) {
    Cursor c = mDb.query(EVENT_TABLE, new String[] { EVENT_ROWID,
            EVENT_NAME }, EVENT_DATE + "='" + date + "'" ,
            null, null, null, null);

return c;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CursorTreeAdapter needs a "_id" field in the cursor. If you have this field in your database just add it to your fetchGroup and fetchChildren query.

Otherwise add "rowid as _id". This uses SQLites internal numbering of rows.

[Android Reference CursorTreeAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html)

Comment: I would swear on a stack of bibles I read through that link three times and missed that bit about _id being required.  It's working now.  Now I just need to get it working in a fragment.  :p  But that might be a question for another day if I run into issues.  Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

Before you can get data from a Cursor, you have to call cursor.moveToFirst(); otherwise it's not initialized. You missed this in your getChildrenCursor() function.

Add:

```
groupCursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not the problem (although I did add a moveToFirst() just in case, I still got the same error).  The problem seems to be that a column is missing from my cursor, but I sure as heck can't figure out where/how.